# check if exists and than display error message in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to check if *personalNumber* exists in db and than display message to user. [I'm trying that using this](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/check-instantly-if-username-exists-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation) but I have one problem:

I've pasted this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesIdExist(string personalNumber)
{
  var user = db.PRT_PARTNERS.Find(personalNumber);

  return Json(user == null);
}
```

but it throws an exception on find:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type of one of the primary key values did
>   not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for
>   details.

What's wrong?

here's my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "მოცემული ველი სავალდებულოა")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{11}$", ErrorMessage = "გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ 11 ნიშნა რიცხვი")]
[Display(Name = "პირადი ნომერი")]
[Remote("doesIdExist", "Partners", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "მოცემული პირადი ნომერი უკვე არსებობს ბაზაში")]
public string personalNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the type of `personalNumber` in the DB?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's VARCHAR2(50). It's same thing that's nvarchar on ms sql. But in db it's name is PERSONAL_NUMBER

Comment: `var user = db.PRT_PARTNERS.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.personalNumber==personalNumber);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
db.PRT_PARTNERS.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.PersonalNumber==personalNumber);
```

or

```
db.PRT_PARTNERS.Any(x=>x.PersonalNumber==personalNumber);
```

Find method is used with keys. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned.

Answer (score 1):

[From comment on the question]

> But in db it's name is PERSONAL_NUMBER

But the model says it is `personalNumber`.

So you need to tell EF:

1. It is the key column: use [`Key` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. It has a different name in the database: use [`Column` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesIdExist(string personalNumber)
    {
//db.PRT_PARTNERS.Where(x=>x.PersonalNumber==personalNumber);

      var user = db.PRT_PARTNERS.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.personalNumber==personalNumber);

      return Json(user == null);
    }
```